# moving User directory failed mlink

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, mklink

I followed this tutorial:

[move user folder](http://maxmakedesign.co.uk/how-to/136/move-all-user-folders-to-another-hard-drive-windows-7)

And after restarting my pc and logging in, i get this error message:

"C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desk top refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet or your network, and then try again. If it still cannot be located, the information might have been moved to a different location."

What did i possibly do wrong?
And how can I fix this?

EDIT
Some extra info, the drive letters changed after i logged on. When i was in recovery mode, my C drive was G and my D drive was K drive was H.
Not sure if this is important.

Comment: Does C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop exist on your PC?

Comment: no the desktop isn't in systemprofile folder.

Comment: Try making it then?

Comment: How do i do that? But what about the rest of the documents then? Didn't the mklink failed since it isn't the drive letter i made the link on?

Comment: File > New Folder. This place doesn't look like it should hold any actual files. On Windows 7, Everything is stored in C:\Users\Username.

Comment: Should the desktop folder be empty when created? And how about the mklink? If i try entering the C:|users folder, i get the same error message. So the mklink isn't working, am i right? How do i fix it so that it poins to the H:\Users dir?

Comment: Generally new folder's are empty when you make them, yes. What command did you use to make the link. Are the files where you would expect them to be in the new Users folder?

Comment: Yes they are where i expect them to be. I used the site i posted in my question. My C drive was G in recovery mode. The drive i mirrored the users folder was K in recovery mode, but in normal mode the drive is H. Do i need to reconfigure the Junction?

Comment: I have no idea what the question means. Does the error go away if you create the folder?

Comment: I haven't created the folder yet. Because i moved everything to a different drive. If this 'desktop' error goes away, how do i know 'my documents' isn't next? And then 'music' and then whatever?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6244/discussion-between-jikag-and-yustme)